# UISegmentedControl not changing when app theme is being changed?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to create 2 themes for an app - light and dark one.

When switching between them, the `UISegmentedControl` is not being changed. It keeps the original state. Not sure why though. I'm sure I'm missing something or doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what.

```
class DiscoverVC: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         segmentedControl.addUnderlineForSelectedSegment()
     }

     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)
         applyTheme()
     }
}

extension DiscoverVC {

    fileprivate func applyTheme() {
         segmentedControl.tintColor = Theme.current.tint
    }
}



extension UISegmentedControl{

func removeBorder() {
        let backgroundImage = UIImage.getColoredRectImageWith(color: UIColor.clear.cgColor, andSize: self.bounds.size)
        self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
        self.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .highlighted, barMetrics: .default)

        let deviderImage = UIImage.getColoredRectImageWith(color: UIColor.clear.cgColor, andSize: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: self.bounds.size.height))
        self.setDividerImage(deviderImage, forLeftSegmentState: .selected, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: Theme.current.segmentedControl_unselectedColor, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: Fonts.OpenSans_Regular, size: 13)!], for: .normal)
        self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: Theme.current.segmentedControl_tintColor, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: Fonts.OpenSans_Bold, size: 13)!], for: .selected)
    } 

    func addUnderlineForSelectedSegment() {
        removeBorder()
        let underlineWidth: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.width / CGFloat(self.numberOfSegments)
        let underlineHeight: CGFloat = 2.0
        let underlineXPosition = CGFloat(selectedSegmentIndex * Int(underlineWidth))
        let underLineYPosition = self.bounds.size.height - 1.0
        let underlineFrame = CGRect(x: underlineXPosition, y: underLineYPosition, width: underlineWidth, height: underlineHeight)
        let underline = UIView(frame: underlineFrame)
        underline.backgroundColor = Theme.current.segmentedControl_tintColor
        underline.tag = 1
        self.addSubview(underline)
    }

    func changeUnderlinePosition() {
        guard let underline = self.viewWithTag(1) else {return}
        let underlineFinalXPosition = (self.bounds.width / CGFloat(self.numberOfSegments)) * CGFloat(selectedSegmentIndex)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            underline.frame.origin.x = underlineFinalXPosition
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Working Amazingly. Try This code. **Swift 4**

```
segment.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1)
```

Must check your Theme Current color.

Comment: The tint color I've setup works. That's not the point. It should switch back and forth between the light and dark theme that I have. And the problem is that once the view controller is being loaded, it never changes the color theme of the segmented control.

Answer (score 0):

In this removeBorder func, you are removing everything from the SegmentedControl (border, textColour, Separator etc.)

Then setting the tint colour will change the colour of what? there you have images for everything.

I am not sure about, if that is the only cause. You should try commenting this and check, if the tint colour applies or not.

```
func addUnderlineForSelectedSegment() {
    //removeBorder()
    YOUR Existing CODE HERE   
}
```

Try it, if that was the cause.

Also, confirm if you are getting the colour value from **Theme.current.tint** or not.

Comment: The `removeBorder()` actually removes the border around each segmented control element. Witout it, it's the default `UISegmentedControl` with an addition to an underline, but the point is for that default UI to be changed into an underline.

Comment: as you are removing the border and separator and adding underline. the same can be achieved the the custom UI, with Two Buttons and a view for underline. then after setting up the proper outlet's you can set the colour to buttons based on the selected theme.